# rspec: augment hash with to_json method from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails

I am in the middle of refactoring out part of a ruby on rails codebase into a ruby gem. As part of the process, I have to shift some test cases over to the gem.

For one of the tests:

```
describe A::B do
  describe "#someMethod" do
    let(:user_hash) { {'id' => 3, "username" => "user", "email" => "email@some.domain"} }
      it "return the base64 message" do
        described_class.message(user_hash).should ==
          Base64.encode64(user_hash.to_json).gsub("\n", "")
      end
```

The thing is, plain hashes do not have the `to_json` method, so I keep getting a `NoMethodError` when I run the tests. The `to_json` method seems to be derived from `activeresource` (https://github.com/rails/activeresource). How do I now augment the hash with the `to_json` method?

Thank you.

Comment: Add `require 'json'` at the top.

Comment: hi vinodadhikary, that worked! Post it officially as the answer? Do you know of a way to find out where such methods are actually from? I am using RubyMine to find out and it gives me this whole list of possible implementations

Comment: please see my answer.  I've tried to answer your question in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you encounter a [`NoMethodError`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/NoMethodError.html) then it means that you don't have required libraries loaded.  Add **`require 'json'`** in your test case where you need to use the method `to_json`.

To answer your question in your comment:

> Do you know of a way to find out where such methods are actually from? I am using RubyMine to find out and it gives me this whole list of possible implementations

Really, search engines come to the rescue when you are looking for functionalities unknown to you.  Probably not an appealing answer but that's how I learn :)  While writing this answer I did [this search on Google](https://www.google.com/#q=ruby+hash+to_json) and the first result is the answer to your  question.

Comment: Haha I see... looks like my googling skills can be improved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you use vim and Ctags, you can put the cursor on the method name and press <C-]> to follow the tag into the source.